# Google Maps V3 -> Is it possible to get properties from Geojson using lat lng coordinates or other information from search box?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, typescript, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm using an external `geojson-file` to add layers to my Google Map. This file contains two properties per area that I would like to access when searching. I can easily fetch the properties if the user clicks on an area or uses any of the other supported event handlers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#add_event_handlers

```
this.map.data.addListener('mouseover', (event) => {
    console.log(event.feature.getProperty('VD'));
});
```

However I would like to get what `geojson` area I'm in when searching and from that access these properties. Is this possible to do?

```
searchBox.addListener('places_changed', () => {
    var places = this.searchBox.getPlaces();
    ...
    places.forEach((place) => {
    ...
```

[image]

Comment: To the person voting down questions with the google-maps tag. Please say why you are voting down so that the questions can be better written in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [containsLocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#poly) utility to check if a LatLng location is contained by a Polygon.

So in a `for` loop get all features in your `Data layer` (populated with `loadGeoJson()` or `addGeoJson()`), get each geometry and create a Polygon to use with the `containsLocation()` function.

For example, the following code checks if `loc` (LatLng) is contained in one of the features of `feats` array:

```
inWhichArea = function(map, loc) {
  for (var i in feats) {
    var area = feats[i].getGeometry();
    var poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
      paths: area.getAt(0).getArray(),
      map: map,
      clickable: false
    });
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(loc, poly)) {
      return feats[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/sgtpop4f/

Comment: I would like to buy you a beer but I hope my thanks are enough. I had to make some small modifications since my features were `MultiPolygon` and not `Polygon`. Simple change: `paths: area.getArray()[0].getAt(0).getArray()` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.MultiPolygon

Comment: A warning: running this query will create new polygons and display them on the map. If the polygons have a semi-transparant fill, this will be visible, as the overall fill color of the stacked polygons gets less transparant each time the query is run.

Comment: @vicmortelmans is correct -- to not show the extra polys on the map, remove the `map` parameter to the `Polygon` constructor

Comment: @Ogglas -- thanks for pointing this out. To handle mixed `Polygon`s and `MultiPolygon`s, I had to loop over the `Data.Polygon`s in `multipolygonArea.getArray()` and construct `Polygon`s from each of those

Comment: I know this is years old, but I'm working on somethng like this now, and I'm trying to get multiple features working right now, but with no luck.   Can someone do a fiddle showing a multi-feature example? @vicmortelmans