# Google Maps V3 -> Is it possible to trigger the on click event on a specific coordinate (lat, lng) programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This question is related to my question here:

[Google Maps V3 -> Is it possible to get properties from Geojson using lat lng coordinates or other information from search box?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47972992/google-maps-v3-is-it-possible-to-get-properties-from-geojson-using-lat-lng-co)

Since it is possible to trigger a click event programmatically like this, I'm wondering if I can trigger a click event on a given lat/lng position in the same way?

Example code:

`google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');`

Pseudo code of what I would like to do:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(place.geometry.location, 'click');
```

[How to trigger the onclick event of a marker on a Google Maps V3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730929/how-to-trigger-the-onclick-event-of-a-marker-on-a-google-maps-v3)

Given the documentation it is really a long shot, but it would solve my current problem.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#event

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try passing additional arguments to `trigger` method:

```
var e = {
  latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(-35, 151)
};
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click', e);
```

Here is a working example showing infoWindow every time map is clicked (or on programmatic trigger): https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/5ndjq8ge/

Comment: Thanks, I needed to trigger the data on click but that only required a small modification. Code example for that: `google.maps.event.trigger(this.map.data, 'click', { coord: place.geometry.location, number: 2 });`